# Facebook's page plugin wont show in my HTML

Tags: html, facebook, plugins

I have a small problem here. I tried to place the "Facebook page plugin" - plugin on a test website. I copied this code from the official Facebook's plugin page:

```html
<!-- 1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening <body> tag.  -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- 2. Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page. -->

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PrekuStojko" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/PrekuStojko"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/PrekuStojko">Преку Стојко photography</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

So, my code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FB pageplugin test</title>

</head>
<body>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PrekuStojko"
       data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
       <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/PrekuStojko">
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PrekuStojko">Преку Стојко photography</a></blockquote
       ></div></div>


</body>
```

And when I run it, I don't see the plugin - Only one line linked text of my page.

```
Преку Стојко photography
```

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code on [fbrell.com](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2dc9496326b4827c36026a1ff0ae4be8) and it worked fine. Can you please re-test? You can check your JS console to see what errors you're getting for your implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try whith Iframe... (replace "NamePage" for your Page)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zqJV.png)

Comment: please make it as a comment